# Scala: Set operations that update the collection?

Tags: scala, collections, set, mutable

I am looking at the mutable `Set` class and see `union`, `intersect`, `diff`, etc. All of these set operations create a new `Set`. I was curious if there is a way to update the `Set` rather than create a new one. Otherwise, I have to switch from `val` to `var` or I have to follow up with additional steps.

In case I'm not being clear, consider .NET's `HashSet` class. It has `IntersectWith`, `ExceptWith` and `UnionWith` that modify the collection. Whereas the LINQ extension methods `Intersect`, `Except` and `Union` create new collections. I'm hoping to find something equivalent to the "With" variants.

Here's an inefficient approach that rebuilds the collection from scratch:

```
val temp = original.diff(other)
original.clear()
original ++= temp
```

Obviously, it would be more efficient to do this:

```
for (value <- other if original.contains(value)) {
    original.remove(value)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean switch `var` to `val` maybe? :)

Comment: Nope, `val` to `var`. I want to maintain the same reference to the same collection. I want to *mutate* that collection rather than replace the reference to a new collection.

Comment: My bad. Quite right. A `val` to a mutable set. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html#operations-in-class-mutableset

For example:

> Additions:      xs += x   Adds element x to set xs as a side effect and
>   returns xs itself.

So just ignore the returned value. The set should be updated in-place.

Comment: Imagine I wanted to take a `diff` so that the original `Set` no longer contained the values in another set. The original collection should shrink. I would need to find the elements needing removed and then `-=` them from the original set. Following?

Comment: Well that's not what you asked :-)  You can `-=` a sequence of items, which should have the effect you want. `-=` should have no effect for items that are not in the set.